# Initialize class object variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created a class for example

```
class Result
    @@min = 0
    @@max = 0
    def initialize(min, max)
        @@max.min = min
        @@max.max = max
    end
end

result = Result.new(1, 10)
result.max
```

Same as other lang. like php, C# etc I have created a class and pass a value and since it has initialize method it will should now contains the object values but when I try to print out

```
puts result.min
puts result.max
```

it says undefined method `min`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ruby, `@@` before a variable means it's a class variable. What you need is the single `@` before the variable to create an instance variable. When you do `Result.new(..)`, you are creating an instance of the class `Result`.

You don't need to create default values like this:

```
@@min = 0
@@max = 0
```

You can do it in the `initialize` method

```
def initialize(min = 0, max = 0)
```

This will initialize `min` and `max` to be zero if no values are passed in.

So now, your `initialize` method should like something like

```
def initialize(min=0, max=0)
    @min = min
    @max = max
end
```

Now, if you want to be able to call `.min` or `.max` methods on the instance of the class, you need to create those methods (called setters and getters)

```
def min # getter method
  @min
end

def min=(val) # setter method
  @min = val
end
```

Now, you can do this:

```
result.min     #=> 1
result.min = 5 #=> 5
```

Ruby has shortcuts for these setters and getters:

- `attr_accessor`: creates the setter and getter methods.
- `attr_reader`: create the getter method.
- `attr_writer`: create the setter method.

To use those, you just need to do `attr_accessor :min`. This will create both methods for `min`, so you can call and set min values directly via the instance object.

Now, you code should look like this

```
class Result
    attr_accessor :min, :max
    def initialize(min=0, max=0)
        @min = min
        @max = max
    end
end

result = Result.new(1, 10)
result.max #=> 10
```

Comment: If for some reason you really need all instances of `Result` to share the same value, look at `cattr_accessor` - but that would mean that initializing a second result would overwrite the value you set in the first one!

Comment: so all I need is the attr_accessor, It works men thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context here it's hard to say exactly what you're looking to do. I suspect what you actually want is an instance variable. In which case you would do:

```
class Result
  attr_accessor :min, :max

  def initialize(min, max)
    @max = min

    @max = max
  end
end
```

Class variables in Ruby and are best avoided unless you really need them. If you actually do you could do this:

```
class Result
  @@min = 0

  @@max = 0

  def self.min
    @@min
  end

  def self.min=(new_min)
    @@min = new_min
  end

  def self.max
    @@max
  end

  def self.max=(new_max)
   @@max = new_max
  end

  def initialize(min, max)
    @@min = min

    @@max = max
  end

  def min
    @@min
  end

  def max
    @@max
  end
end

puts Result.min

puts Result.max

result = Result.new(1, 10)

puts result.min

puts result.max

puts Result.min

puts Result.max
```

Be warned though, [class variables are tricky](https://www.sitepoint.com/class-variables-a-ruby-gotcha/).