# Not creating class object - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a User class in Ruby On Rails App, and when I call 
`NETWORKING::User.new(1,"Testing")` , it returns `*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)`

Not sure why?

```
class NETWORKING::User 
   mattr_writer :id, :name

 class << self

    def initialize(id, name)
        @id = id
        @fullname = name

    end

end
end
```

Comment: Why did you include `class << self`, what did you think that would accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

`class << self` serves no purpose here except to break your code. Remove it:

```
class NETWORKING::User 
  attr_accessor :id, :name

  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @fullname = name
  end
end
```

Comment: But when I remove it and try to access the id using NETWORKING::User.id it shows undefined method.

Comment: @Wings2fly That makes no sense at all. What should `NETWORKING::User.id` return? It seems like this is a fundamental misunderstanding in how OOP works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39694071/initialize-class-object-variable-in-ruby Referred to the answer here.

Comment: user = NETWORKING::User.new(1,"Test") ; puts user.id

Comment: There is no instance of `class << self` in that link.

Comment: I removed self, but its still returning undefined method 'id' for class - error.

Comment: You need to add an accessor for `id`. Try `attr_accessor :id`.